# Boiling in completely filled vessel

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-diagram

Suppose we completely fill a vessel with water and then close it in such a way that no matter can escape from it. If we now heat the vessel to 373K then what will happen inside vessel?

Comment: The boiling point of water increases with increasing pressure. Yes?

Comment: It depends on the thermal expansion coefficient of the vessel compared with the water, and how much pressure the vessel can withstand without bursting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a homework it is over a year old and I can answer it.

What will happen is that the pressure inside the vessel will increase enormously. To find $\Delta P$ assume that the volume of the vessel does not change. Then we are dealing with a constant $V$ process. Go to the $PV$ graph of steam and draw a vertical line from the initial state to the final temperature, then read the pressure. It's huge!